# How can I gently test the Peroneal Strike on myself?

Tags: striking

[This Youtube](https://youtu.be/CRSldaaVJRk) shows this strike at the 1:28 mark, and the striked man just topples. Obviously I don't want to toppple or cause any pain to myself. I just want to feel  the https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peroneal_strike a little.

I followed these instructions on [Quora](https://www.quora.com/How-do-you-give-someone-a-dead-leg/answer/Rick-Hamilton), but didn't feel the peroneal nerve.

> First, learn to locate the target nerves. Stand erect, and relaxed, with your hands hanging at your sides and your thumbs resting along the side seam of your trouser legs. Press inward, against your thighbone, with the middle fingers of each hand.
>
> The spots where your fingers are pressing will correspond to the area circled in the drawing below. That is your target.
>
> Within the circle are the femoral, perineal, and sciatic nerves. Striking any or both with a hard penetrating blow will cause sharp pain, then numbness in the thigh, and the leg will buckle. Your opponent will have great difficulty walking, or even standing, for a minute or so, then the discomfort will begin to dissipate.

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The effect of the spot you indicate is known colloquially as a "dead leg".

You can strike this spot without any great danger, it simply induces a throbbing pain and a temporary loss of control to the muscles in the area.

The description in Quora:

> Stand erect, and relaxed, with your hands hanging at your sides and your thumbs resting along the side seam of your trouser legs. Press inward, against your thighbone, with the middle fingers of each hand.

is correct, but you won't feel anything with your fingers - that point is well protected by muscle and you cannot reasonably access it just by pressing with your fingers.

If you want to strike it yourself, use your thumb knuckle (and remember to go a little lower - your thumb is naturally a bit higher than that point when your arm is fully extended).

However you can only hit it yourself with limited force. If you really want to experience it properly, have someone kick you on that spot - it won't take much force to experience the full sensation.